# React forwardRef to access a method and not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

I'm working on a project in React 18, in TypeScript. There is a page header, inside of which is a Nav component. I'm using Bootstrap-react's `NavBar` component for that nav. I can do a manual toggle of the collapsible nav, and that's fine, it's all inside the same React component.

But now I need to access that toggler from the parent `Header` component, of which `Nav` is child. I'm trying to use `forwardRef` to accomplish this, and running into problems.

So inside of my `Nav` React component, I'm using Bootstrap's `NavBar`. There is a method I wrote to toggle the collapsible navbar, for actions that don't collapse it normally. It looks like this:

```
const toggleNav = () => {
  const toggle: HTMLButtonElement | null = document.querySelector(
    "button#toggle-button"
  );
  const collapseTell = document.querySelector("div#basic-navbar-nav");
  const showing = collapseTell
    ? collapseTell.className.indexOf("show") !== -1
    : false;
  if (toggle && showing) toggle.click();
};
```

This leverages the classNames that Bootstrap's `NavBar` component creates.

But now I am creating an additional element inside `Header` (not yet its own component, at least until I solve this issue), which, when interacted with, needs to collapse the `NavBar` Bootstrap component. I see a couple of ways to do this by brute force:

(1) just put this new element inside the `Nav` React component, where it can also access the same `toggleNav` method.
(2) Re-create `toggleNav` inside of the `Header` React component.

I don't want to do either of these: (1) is not semantic at all...even if I don't break this new element out into its own component, it definitely doesn't belong in `Nav`. (2) doubles down on what feels like something kludgy to begin with, and I would like to avoid it. It appears that `forwardRef` is the appropriate way to do this, and I'm having some struggles with it.

Here is the parent component:

```
interface headerProps {
  prop1: ...
  prop2: ...
  prop3: ...
  (etc)
}

export function Header({
  prop1, prop2, prop3, ...
}: headerProps) {

  // various routines and states and things here  

  const navRef = useRef();

  // handlers and such here

  return (
    <header>
      
      // assorted JSX stuff here

      <Nav
        navProp1={}
        navProp2={}
        (etc)
        ref={navRef}
      />
    </header>
  );
}
```

Now here is the Nav component, in its own module:

```
interface headerNavProps {
  navProp1: ...
  navProp2: ...
  etc
}

export const Nav = forwardRef(
  ({navProp1, navProp2, etc}: headerNavProps, ref) => {
    
    // various states, handlers and doo-dads

    const toggleNav = () => {
      const toggle: HTMLButtonElement | null = document.querySelector(
        "button#toggle-button"
      );
      const collapseTell = document.querySelector("div#basic-navbar-nav");
      const showing = collapseTell
        ? collapseTell.className.indexOf("show") !== -1
        : false;
      if (toggle && showing) toggle.click();
    };


    return (
      <Navbar
        expand={...}
        collapseOnSelect={true}
        bg="transparent"
        variant="dark"
      >
        <Container>

          // contents of the navbar

        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
);
```

I haven't even gotten to trying to reference `toggleNav` yet. Though VSCode does not show any compilation errors as I have it here, what I get in the browser (both the viewport and the console), is:

```
Component is not a function. (In 'Component(props, secondArg)', 'Component' is an instance of Object)
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46501:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49787:32
...(continue stack trace)
```

So, my questions, finally:

--What am I doing incorrectly? I THINK I've got the syntax for `forwardRef` correct.

--I'm not interested in referencing a DOM node with the `forwardRef`, but that method `toggleNav`. How would I do that? I THINK the way to do it is, from within the header, reference `navRef.current.toggleNav`, without having to attach the `ref` property to `toggleNav`...but I'm not sure.

--Do I even need to use `forwardRef`? As I'm looking around the Web for answers, I see that I possibly don't even need to use it, just do `useRef` from within the `Header` component, reference the `Nav` component with it, and then reference `navRef.current.toggleNav`. If I try to do that, simply that and back `forwardRef` out of `Nav`, then I get a compile error, since `Nav` seems to treat `ref` as a prop, and wants to know what gives.

Thanks for helping me untangle this!

EDIT:

I just tried it without using `forwardRef` at all. Just did `useRef` within `Header`, attached that ref to `Nav`, and within `Nav` added a prop `ref: any` to its props interface. The page renders...but on the console I get...

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. The part of me that wants to be "elegant" in my coding just wants to believe there is a cleaner way to do it...but you're right, that's probably the best way to go about it.

Comment: Turned the comment into an answer instead.

Comment: I haven't formed an opinion which approach I would recommend but just wanted to let you know that the missing piece in your _imperative approach_ is React's `useImperativeHandle` hook. I've covered it in a [blog post](https://dev.to/teetotum/modalopen-imperative-component-api-in-react-3inc) some time ago.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I will view that post, and see if I can get it working in that method before I follow Mike's suggestion, at least to better understand the use of forwardRef. :)

Comment: Martin, thanks, that helped a lot. I was able to just send back exactly that method as the ref, worked brilliantly. Going to also test Mike's solution and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for refs or even "React" methodologies: note that your `toggleNav` doesn't actually depend on anything in React, it's just plain browser JS. As such, you can take it out of the `Nav` component, put it in its own `toggle-navbar.ts` file, and then have anything that needs to use it, import it.

Because remember that you're always in JavaScript: if something doesn't specifically rely on React features, you don't need to use React to make it work, and you'll end up with cleaner React code because of it.

(And that even goes for things like effects, which by definition consist of "not React" code that has to kick in after React is done generating things. Zero reason to have a giant const block inside your component function, write a normal, proper JS function that takes the data it needs as arguments, and lives in its own module, either on its own, or with a bunch of other effects. Now your React code is super clean, with useEffect imported from react, named effects imported from your effect file(s), and clean `useEffect(() => namedEffect(...), [...deps])` lines in your components)

Comment: Thanks very much! I will try this out. I guess thinking about it in this way changes my philosophy on something else: I've been trying to do data queries inside `useEffect` but running into problems because of course I can't use `useMutation` or `useQuery` inside of `useEffect`. But I don't HAVE to use those React hooks, I can just use graphQL inside of a JavaScript module. That makes all the sense in the world.

Comment: That's exactly it. React has a whole bunch of super useful utilities "for doing things inside components", but that doesn't mean that what you're triggering is something that _has_ to happen "inside your component" or even in React at all. The best components model only the state they need, set up calls that will get the component the data it needs, and then renders the presentation+interaction layer for that data. Anything more than a short bit of trivial code and you're almost certainly doing too much inside the component itself, with code that isn't _actually_ tied to that component.

Comment: Mike, that solution worked a treat. Thanks for your help! Now I'm energized by the change in perspective to reevaluate how much I'm having each component do.